# Incorrect number of query parameters in Moodle *How to get the external links from course page

Tags: moodle, adhoc-queries

My Dear
I tried   to run the following ad-hoc database query  in Moodle but i got it error

there any way to fix it   , thanks

*My target to find  all the external links (URL) from course page

```
SELECT
        concat('<a target="_new" href=%%WWWROOT%%/course/view.php?id=',
                c.id, '">', c.fullname, '</a>') AS Course
        ,c.shortname,r.name
        ,(
            SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname,' ', u.lastname) AS Teacher
            FROM prefix_role_assignments AS ra
                JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
                JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
            WHERE ra.roleid = 3 
            AND ctx.instanceid = c.id 
            LIMIT 1
          ) AS Teacher
        ,concat('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/mod/resource/view.php?id=',
                r.id, '">', r.name, '</a>') AS Resource
FROM prefix_resource AS r
    JOIN prefix_course AS c ON r.course = c.id
WHERE r.reference LIKE 'https://stackoverflow.com/%'
```

Error message :

```
" Error when executing the query: ERROR: Incorrect number of query 
parameters. Expected 2, got 0"
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the actual prepared statement, which we need to see in order to help you.

Comment: I have added my codes

Comment: And please ALWAYS show us ALL the error message not a summary as you will always miss something useful to us

Comment: that is a php error and no mysql error, so oyu need to show the php code

Comment: @nbk  
thanks for your replay It's a query on Ad-hoc database queries on Moodle  , All queries works except this one
I just need All external links in all pages in my moodle

Comment: you will find this query 
COURSE RESOURCES REPORTS (Book, File, Folder, Label, Page, URL)
All resources that link to some specific external website
+ link to course + who's the teacher + link to external resource

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing SQL statements in Moodle, any '?' characters are used to indicate placeholders for parameters that need to be provided along with the query.

From the style of your query, I'm assuming you're using report_customsql or block_configurablereports for your query, so you won't have the option of providing such parameters.

If you look at the documentation here: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Custom_SQL_queries_report you will see that the workaround for this is to replace any '?' characters in your query with '%%Q%%'.

So the fixed query should look like:

```
SELECT concat('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/course/view.php%%Q%%id=',c.id,'">',c.fullname,'</a>') AS Course,
    c.shortname,r.name, (SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname,' ', u.lastname) AS Teacher
FROM prefix_role_assignments AS ra
JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
WHERE ra.roleid = 3 AND ctx.instanceid = c.id LIMIT 1) AS Teacher,
concat('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/mod/resource/view.php%%Q%%id=',r.id,'">',r.name,'</a>') AS Resource
FROM prefix_resource AS r
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON r.course = c.id
WHERE r.reference LIKE 'https://stackoverflow.com/%'
```